# how can I git diff a file over specific line or lines?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-blame

Is it possible to ask `git diff` to only check changes over some lines on a file? Like if I run `git diff some-file`, I see many many changes.... different sections of the file, but if I only want to see the differences related to one specific line of the file? Or only a handful of lines? Is there something like -L from `git blame`?

Answer (score 2):

Git currently has no way to populate its inputs to its various diff algorithms from anything less than an entire input file.

The actual diff code (in `xdiff/*` in the Git source) could do the job, if you just fed it the right inputs, but there's nothing in Git to do that.